# React-bootstrap Carousels rendering all together vertically

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel, react-bootstrap

I am just trying to render a very very basic straight carousel.

But its not even rendering properly. Obviously i might be missing something very silly.
Its rendering all the images all together vertically. Also the indicator are not aligned properly. Is there some css required. If yes from where can i get it.

[image: Carousel]

```
<Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
      alt="First slide"
    />
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
      alt="Third slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
      alt="Third slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>;
```

Please help me im totally stuck in this issue.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of how the images are rendering and any errors displayed in your console?

Comment: @WaterTrash No error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the bootstrap file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

More details here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3691